# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: caused by JerseyClientBuilder

Tags: jersey, weblogic, jersey-2.0, weblogic12c, jersey-client

pom.xml dependencies

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-apache-connector</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Using Jersey 2.33 version and `javax.ws.rs-api` version 2.1.1 jars and from below sample code, I'm trying to invoke

```java
new JerseyClientBuilder()
        .withConfig(clientConfig)
        .executorService(executorService)
```

and getting below error

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder.executorService(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)Ljavax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder;

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class SimpleHttpClient {
    
    @Resource 
    private ManagedExecutorService executorService;

    @Override
    public ClientBuilder newHttpClientBuilder(ClientSettings settings) {
        ClientConfig configuration = new ClientConfig();
        configuration.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        configuration.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(settings.getConnectionPoolSize());
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(50);
        configuration.property(ApacheClientProperties.CONNECTION_MANAGER, connectionManager);
        configuration.connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());
        return new JerseyClientBuilder().withConfig(configuration).executorService(executorService);

    }
}
```

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: Weblogic server 12.2.1.3

Comment: That's the problem. WebLogic already has it's own version of Jersey, and it's conflicting with the version you are trying to use in your project.

Comment: Configured Weblogic to use Jersey from application by weblogic.xml
Using Jersey-Client 2.33 version to use JerseyClientBuilder.

It is expecting ExecutorService type of java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService; and I am giving ManagedExecutorService type of javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService


 @Resource 
    private ManagedExecutorService executorService;

JerseyClientBuilder().withConfig(configuration).executorService(executorService);

Comment: Any suggestions to execute ManageExecutorService by Jersey

Comment: `ManageExecutorService` extends `ExecutorService` so that is not any problem.